# Find table row index that contains text JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find table row index from a link which is on the table. The code I am trying, always returning value 3. I have two many rows on my page. My code is -

Table (example) -

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(Rank1)">Rank1</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery -

```
function findindex(RName) {
    var val = $('table tbody tr td div a:contains(' + RName + ')').index();
    alert(val);
});
```

Please someone help me how to find the table row index value.

Thanks

Comment: What is `Rank1`??? `findindex(Rank1)`

Comment: @Rank1 is link value

Comment: Can you post relevant code you are using because here `Rank1` is undefined and your snippet as typo. Anyway, if you want index of clicked row on clicking on anchor, this isn't really what you should use. Instead, see e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/fxf7nm5j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `index()` on that selector, you're in fact getting the index of the `a` element. The *text* selector is working fine, but after finding the element with the mached text, you need to find it's `tr` and get it's index:

```
$('table tbody tr td div a:contains("' + RName + '")').closest("tr").index();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L9py0q43/)

Also, you have some syntax errors:

```
onclick="findindex(Rank1)"
```

Should be:

```
onclick="findindex('Rank1')"
```

Or even better:

```
onclick="findindex(this)"
```

And the function:

```
function findindex(element) {
    var val = $('table tbody tr td div a:contains("' + element.innerText + '")').closest("tr").index();
    alert(element.innerText + "=" + val);
};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L9py0q43/1/)

Note that I have added quotes to your css selector:

```
'table tbody tr td div a:contains("' + element.innerText + '")'
                                  ^ this                    ^ and this
```

To produce this result `'table tbody tr td div a:contains("Rank1")'`

---

Now, the best thing you can do with jQuery:

Remove the `onclick` event attribute from your anchor elements and add a class:

```
<a herf="my link here" class="rank-anchor">Rank1</a>
```

Then bind an event on document load to your table:

```
$("table").on("click", "a.rank-anchor", function() {
    var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    alert(index);
});
```

In the event function, you can see that you don't need the full selector to the `a` element, you already have the element, so you can use `this` to find its `tr`. In this case you don't need to find the element by it's content as well, the event is being called fron it already.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L9py0q43/2/)

Comment: Could be just `$(this).closest('tr').index();` inside a `$('a').click()`

Comment: Also `herf` has to change to `href` ;-)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm trying to show to OP a step by step help.

Comment: Good post but if really OP wants the row index clicking on any descendant anchor, at a starting point he shouldn't use `:contains()` which could bring unrelevant result

Comment: I know. I was just suggesting `$('a').click(function() { var index = $(this).closest('tr').index(); });` would be better and simpler

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm getting there, dude.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(this)">Rank1</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(this)">Rank2</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(this)">Rank3</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(this)">Rank4</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(this)">Rank5</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(this)">Rank6</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>
     <div>
       <a herf="my link here" onclick="findindex(this)">Rank6</a>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript Function :

```
function findindex(obj) {
    var val = $(obj).closest("tr").index();
    alert("Rank = " + val);
};
```